# Get array values by keys

Tags: php, arrays

I am searching for a built in php function that takes array of keys as input and returns me corresponding values.

for e.g. I have a following array

```
$arr = array("key1"=>100, "key2"=>200, "key3"=>300, 'key4'=>400);
```

and I need values for the keys **key2** and **key4** so I have another `array("key2", "key4")`
I need a function that takes this array and first array as inputs and provide me values in response. So response will be `array(200, 400)`

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are asking. Can you clarify, maybe with an example input and output?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a *built in* function, then @Amber has the best answer.  There doesn't appear to be a built-in function that does precisely what you're asking for.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

I think you are searching for [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/array_intersect_key). Example:

```
array_intersect_key(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 5), 
                    array_flip(array('a', 'c')));
```

Would return:

```
array('a' => 1, 'c' => 5);
```

You may use `array('a' => '', 'c' => '')` instead of `array_flip(...)` if you want to have a little simpler code.

Note the array keys are preserved. You should use [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) afterwards if you need a sequential array.

Comment: great answer, is there any shorter way?

Comment: Don't think so. You may write array('a'=>'', 'c'=>'') instead of array_flip(...), but it seems to have different semantic for me.

Comment: Note that this returns an associative array (so in the example of the OP, it wouldn't return `array(200,400)`, but instead `array('key2'=>200,'key4'=>400)`.

Comment: @Amber, does it really matter if it returns `array(0=>100,1=>400)` or `array('key2'=>200,'key4'=>400)`? But in any way, if the resulting array should not display the original keys, just wrap that one liner inside a `array_values()`

Comment: @Yanick: There are edge cases where it *can* matter (consider: `foreach($arr as $index => $val) { ...stuff using $index... }`).

Comment: One consideration that worth to be made about presented solutions is by using `array_intersect_key()`, if second argument has duplicated values they will be overwritten when passing to `array_flip()` because, obviously, array indices are unique. And this doesn't happen with second approach because there is no flipping, making it appropriate for certain cases.

Answer (score 29):

An alternative answer:

```
$keys = array("key2", "key4");

return array_map(function($x) use ($arr) { return $arr[$x]; }, $keys);
```

Comment: If efficiency matters, this solution is calling a function for every element in $keys, which is unnecessarily inefficient.  @Amber has the better answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
foreach($input_arr as $key) {
    $output_arr[] = $mapping[$key];
}
```

This will result in `$output_arr` having the values corresponding to a list of keys in `$input_arr`, based on the key->value mapping in `$mapping`. If you want, you could wrap it in a function:

```
function get_values_for_keys($mapping, $keys) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $output_arr[] = $mapping[$key];
    }
    return $output_arr;
}
```

Then you would just call it like so:

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$values = get_values_for_keys($a, array('a', 'c'));
// $values is now array(1, 3)
```