# get available values existing in array from a list of keys php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array :

```
$array = array('a' => 'value of a', 'b' => 'value of b', 'c' => 'value of c',
    'd' => 'value of d');
```

this list of items :

```
$items = array ('a' => 'value','b'=> 'value','c'=> 'value','d'=> 'value');
```

i want to check if at least one of the keys of $items exist in $array, if so return an array with one / availableones and its/their values.

this is what i have tried so far, but cant get it right :

```
if (array_key_exists('a', $array) || array_key_exists('b', $array)
    || array_key_exists('c', $array) || array_key_exists('d', $array)) { 
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4240153/251735

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a intersection of the keys between two arrays. There's a nice function called `array_intersect_key()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

```
$array = array('a' => 'value of a', 'b' => 'value of b', 'c' => 'value of c', 'd' => 'value of d');
$items = array ('a' => 'value','b'=> 'value','c'=> 'value','d'=> 'value');

print_r(array_intersect_key($array, $items));
```

Comment: this is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function search_keys($needle, $haystack) {
    $matches = array();
    foreach($needle as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $haystack)) {
            $maches[$key] = $haystack[$key];
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

$matches = seach_keys($items, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like this:

```
function check_keys ($items, $array){
    $return = false;
    foreach (array_keys($items) as $key){
        if (isset($array[$key])){
            $return = true;
            break;
       }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
// returns true or false
var_dump (check_keys ($items, $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this

```
$array = array('a' => 'value of a', 'b' => 'value of b', 'c' => 'value of c', 'd' => 'value of d');
$items = array ('a' => 'value','b'=> 'value','c'=> 'value','d'=> 'value');

foreach($items as $key=>$value){
 if (array_key_exists($key,$array)){

  //your code

 }
}
```